# Lynx removes newline characters from post_data input

Tags: dos, postdata, lynx

I am trying to post a file to a URL via the MS-DOS command prompt.  I am using the Lynx browser to do this.  I am able to post my file just fine, but all of the newline characters are removed by Lynx before creating the POST request.  Is it possible to post a file via command line without having the newline characters removed?  The command I am running is:

```
lynx -post_data http://www.myserver.com/myscript.pl < testfile.txt
```

The input file, testfile.txt, looks like this:

```
test=This

is

a

test.;
---
```

The data that actually gets sent across the wire looks like this:

```
test=Thisisatest.;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found cURL to be a far better utility to post a file via MS-DOS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to have your special characters URLENCODED for this to work. According to this [Lynx page](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/lynx/help_files/Lynx_users_guide.html):

> Forms most commonly are submitted to
>   http servers with the content encoded
>   as
>   ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   for analysis by a script, and Lynx
>   treats that as the default if no
>   ENCTYPE is specified in the FORM start
>   tag. However, you can specify a mailto
>   URL as the form's ACTION to  have the
>   form content sent, instead, to an
>   email address. In such cases,  you may
>   wish to specify ENCTYPE="text/plain"
>   in the form markup, so that the
>   content will not be encoded, but
>   remain readable as plain text.

This means that spaces become %20 and newlines become %0A